# How to get value for a const varible after set useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to handle this case:

Source code:

```
const rootStore = useStore();
const { permission } = rootStore;

const [permissionIds, setPermissionIds] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchPermission()
},[]);

const fetchPermission = async () => {
    let _permissionIds = await permission.getPermissionRole('admin/roles/1');

    setPermissionIds(_permissionIds); //(1)
}

const listPermissionIds = permissionIds  //(2)
```

This case: value of listPermissionIds at line (2) is empty

I want to value of listPermissionIds at line (2) is _permissionIds at line (1)

Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: The component will do the initial render before the `fetchPermission` function is ran, so the array is empty. It will then re-render after `setPermissionIds` changes the state, after which `permissionIds` is the value you set it to.

Comment: You will get it on the second render, where is the problem?

Comment: @cbr , I know that. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Could you then clarify what you mean by what you mean by that you want the value at line (2) to be the value at (1)? That is exactly the case after the re-render.

Comment: @DennisVash , thanks for your comment. I have found a solution.

Comment: @cbr, thanks for your comment. I have found a solution.

Comment: @Viet please post your solution as an answer so that others with the same issue can also find the solution in the future :)